# How do I get a rebased branch back to origin?

Tags: git, git-rebase

My colleague and I have recently implemented git, and have just tried to implement rebasing. So, we have a remote `master` branch, cloned locally, and I have a local (and remote) branch called `changes`. Locally, we've done some work on `changes`, so it looks like this:

```
master: A
        \
changes: B-C-D
```

So through an unrelated merge from elsewhere, `master` got upgraded, so we had:

```
master: A-E
        \
changes: B-C-D
```

So, I did a rebase:

```
git checkout changes
git rebase E (via a tag)
```

So, in my local repo, I had:

```
master: A-E
           \
changes:    B-C-D
```

So, I tried to then do a push, but got:

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/changes (you should pull first)
```

Seemingly, the conventional wisdom around was to do a force push to get my work on `changes` back up to `origin/changes`:

```
git push -f origin changes
```

Which responded with:

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/changes (you should pull first)
To /opt/git/online.git
 ! [remote rejected] changes -> changes (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/opt/git/online.git'
```

So, I'm now a bit confused. I assumed the workflow would be that after doing a rebase to my local `changes`, I could get `origin/changes` to line up. Am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `push -f` command requests that your Git client try to push the ref anyway, even if it is not a descendant of the current remote branch. However, the upstream repository can still reject the request.

You can allow this by changing a configuration option in your upstream repository `config` file:

```
[receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = false
```

The [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html) has the following to say about this option:

> **receive.denyNonFastForwards**
>   If you rebase commits that you’ve already pushed and then try to push again, or otherwise try to push a commit to a remote branch that doesn’t contain the commit that the remote branch currently points to, you’ll be denied. This is generally good policy; but in the case of the rebase, you may determine that you know what you’re doing and can force-update the remote branch with a `-f` flag to your push command.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that the defaults precluded this. Indeed, in the upstream repo directory, denyNonFastforwards was set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your last graph isn’t really accurate, as B, C, & D are all new commits, so they’re more like B′, C′, & D′:

```
        master: A-E
                |\
       changes:  \ B′-C′-D′
origin/changes:   B-C-D
```

As can be seen by this new, correct graph, `changes` (D′) is not a child of `origin/changes` (D). You can verify this by seeing that [`git merge-base origin/changes changes`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) is A, and `git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/changes changes` returns 1 (false).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So have I misunderstood what happens here? I can't replace (or shouldn't?) replace origin/changes with changes? How do I get my new b'c'd' commits back to origin?

Comment: Since the remote repository forbids it, you cannot. You may be able to delete the remote branch and then push it, essentially creating a new one. Or you can just do a regular `git merge master` on changes.